# Is a proof of work consensus mechanism that discourages mining in pools possible?

Tags: mining-pools, proof-of-work

Most proof of work cryptocurrencies, including Bitcoin, have most of their hashrate controlled by the biggest mining pools which significantly decreases decentralization. Would it be theoretically possible to create a proof of work algorithm that distributes the block reward to miners relative to how many shares they have submitted? Basically make it so that the algorithm itself is a decentralized mining pool.

Answer (score 1):

> biggest mining pools which significantly decreases decentralization

Not at all. Pools contribute to decentralization. Without pools, small miners would never be able to mine feasibly, because they would never find a block. No matter how much time they spent mining, no block = no reward. Pools allow them a fair share of block rewards proportional to their work.

> Would it be theoretically possible to create a proof of work algorithm that distributes the block reward to miners relative to how many shares they have submitted

It's called [P2Pool](http://p2pool.in/)

Answer (score 0):

Stratum v2 (a protocol for pooled mining) will improve few things:

1. Miner will broadcast block instead of mining pool
2. Signalling bits
3. Choose own transaction set (if refused by pool, miner will know the reason)

https://danielabrozzoni.github.io/posts/20210221-btc-munich.html

For decentralized payouts, maybe we can use discreet log contracts however this depends on mining pool and difficult to change the protocol so that everyone follows it:

1. Miner that broadcasted the mined block (Peer 1), Mining pool (Peer 2)
2. Payout address used in coinbase transaction is 2 of 2 multisig funding address for this DLC
3. Multiple miners with some oracles provide information about value of the shares miners submitted
4. This contract is settled based on M of N oracles and [specifications](https://github.com/discreetlogcontracts/dlcspecs/blob/master/MultiOracle.md) used for multiple oracles